# Phase function of filter

Tags: filters, phase, frequency-response, transfer-function

I have a filter with the transfer function

$$H(z) = 1 - 2z^{-2} + z^{-4}.$$ The task is to find the phase function $\theta (\omega).$

---

**My attempt** is to start by expressing the frequency response 
\begin{align}
H(\omega) &=H(z)\big\vert_{z=e^{j\omega}}\\
&= 1 - 2e^{-2j\omega} + e^{-4j\omega}\\
&=  e^{-2j\omega}( e^{2j\omega} - 2 + e^{-2j\omega})\\
&=  e^{-2j\omega}(2\cos(2\omega)-2)
\end{align}

I think there is a relation of the sort $$H(\omega) = e^{j\theta (\omega)}|H(\omega)|$$

which in my case would give me $$\theta (\omega) = -2\omega.$$

The correct answer is $$\theta (\omega) = -2\omega + \pi.$$ How do I get the extra term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your error comes when you map:

$$
H(\omega) = e^{-j2\omega}\left(2\cos(2\omega)-2\right)
$$

onto the split magnitude/phase representation:

$$
H(\omega) = e^{j\theta(\omega)}|H(\omega)|
$$

Remember a requirement of $|H(\omega)|$; since it is a magnitude, it must always be nonnegative. You implicitly made the assumption that:

$$
|H(\omega)| = 2\cos(2\omega) - 2
$$

The problem is that $2\cos(2\omega) - 2$ is *never* positive. It covers the range $[-4,0]$. So, we must break the expression down slightly differently:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H(\omega) &= -e^{-j2\omega}\left(2-2\cos(2\omega)\right) \\
&= e^{-j2\omega}e^{j\pi}\left(2-2\cos(2\omega)\right) \\
&= e^{j(-2\omega+\pi)}\left(2-2\cos(2\omega)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Above, we took advantage of the fact that $e^{j\pi} = -1$. That is, if you apply a phase shift of $\pm \pi$, it's equivalent to multiplying by $-1$. This expression does fit the split magnitude/phase form that you want, because $2 - 2\cos(2\omega)$ is nonnegative; it fits the requirements to represent a magnitude. Therefore, it follows that:

$$
\angle H(\omega) = -2\omega + \pi
$$

Comment: That's quite explicit for a homework type question, isn't it? :)

Comment: I'm feeling generous today. :)

Comment: This does not change the rest of your answer, but the range should be $[-4,0]$.

Comment: @fibonatic: Indeed it should be. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Answer these two basic questions, and you should be able to solve your problem:

1. What's the sign of the term $2\cos(2\omega)-2$? Can it be a magnitude?
2. What does a term of $\pm \pi$ in the phase do to the sign of an expression?